# How to change value of the variable in one python script from another python script

Tags: python, string

I have to files python1 and python2.

Python2.py has code something like this:

```
import sys
variable1=value1
variable2=value2
#and some python code from here on
```

The python1 script should take the input value for variable1 and variable2 and change the corresponding value in python2.py without tampering the other code.

And example 2:
If any user gives the variable1 value as android. The value of variable1 in python2 should be changed to android

Thanks

Note: python2 is not a configuration file, has many other modules

Comment: do you want to change the source code or the value from one program to another or do you want to change the attribute of the module?

Comment: @User I want to change the source code of python2 from python1

Comment: If you do not want to rewrite the file you may be interested in this module: https://gist.github.com/niccokunzmann/5262590 At least this is an alternative.

Comment: @User this looks perfect.
But when i try to use this it says first it said .conf file is not present.
when i create a conf file with empty contents still doesnot accept.
Will be perfect if i could make it work

Comment: That is sad. I tested it under python2.7 and python3.3 what python do you use? What Error type do you get?

Comment: Were you finally able to solve this? I'm encountering the very same problem and have no ideas...

Answer (score 3):

You can just `import python2` in `python1`, then use `python2.variable1=...`

Comment: Somehow it is not working.
In python2 as i initialize variables, when i execute the python2 again the initializing part is running again and value is getting back to value1